# How do I write a sub-section in LateX?

Tags: latex

I'm writing a Cockburn table and I need a subparagraph for an extension like the ones you can see in the picture (for example "3a1. Renegotiate order."):

[image: example]

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]    

\def\arraystretch{1.5}


\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|X|X|X|}

  \hline Use Case \#N & \multicolumn{3} {l|}{Login Mockup} \\ \hline Goal in
  Context & \multicolumn{3}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr 3\hsize+4\tabcolsep+2\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{%
    L'utente effettua il login sulla piattaforma.  } \\
 \hline Preconditions &
  \multicolumn{3}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr 3\hsize+4\tabcolsep+2\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{%
    L'utente seleziona Login dal menù laterale. } \\
 \hline Success End Conditions &
  \multicolumn{3}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr 3\hsize+4\tabcolsep+2\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{%
    L'utente visualizza la home page.} \\
 \hline Failed End Conditions &
  \multicolumn{3}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr 3\hsize+4\tabcolsep+2\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{%
    Viene visualizzato un messaggio di errore Login fallito che invita l'utente a riprovare o a registrarsi se non ha un account. } \\
 \hline Primary Actor &
  \multicolumn{3}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr 3\hsize+4\tabcolsep+2\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{%
   Utente non registrato. } \\
 \hline Trigger & \multicolumn{3}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr 3\hsize+4\tabcolsep+2\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{%
    L'utente conferma i dati del login premendo sul tasto Login.} \\

  \hline \multirow{2}{*}{Description} & Step & User Action & System \\

  \cline{2-4} & 1 & L'utente inserisce i dati nei relativi campi & \\
  \cline{2-4} & 2 & L'utente invia i dati premendo sul pulsante "Login" & \\
  \cline{2-4} & 3 & L'applicativo invia i dati al server e prova il login & \\
  \cline{2-4} & 4 & L'applicativo completa il login e visualizza la home page & \\
 \hline \multirow{2}{*}{Extensions} & Step &
  User Action & System \\
 \cline{2-4} & 1a & L'utente richiede l'accesso con Facebook & \\ \hline
  \multirow{2}{*}{Subvariations} & Step & User Action & System \\

  \cline{2-4} & & & \\
 \hline Notes & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{} \\
 \hline


\end{tabularx}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I have to insert the subparagraph in this line before the last &

```
 \cline{2-4} & 1a & L'utente richiede l'accesso con Facebook & \\ \hline
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are anyway doing your numbering manually, you could just use something like `\newline \hspace*{1em} 3a1. abc`

Unrelated to your problem, but a tabular with such narrow columns usually looks much better if the text is left aligned instead of justified.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]    

\def\arraystretch{1.5}


\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|Y|Y|Y|}
  \hline 
  Use Case \#N & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{Login Mockup} \\ \hline 
  Goal in Context & \multicolumn{3}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr 3\hsize+4\tabcolsep+2\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{%
    L'utente effettua il login sulla piattaforma.  } \\
 \hline Preconditions &
  \multicolumn{3}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr 3\hsize+4\tabcolsep+2\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{%
    L'utente seleziona Login dal menù laterale. } \\
 \hline Success End Conditions &
  \multicolumn{3}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr 3\hsize+4\tabcolsep+2\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{%
    L'utente visualizza la home page.} \\
 \hline Failed End Conditions &
  \multicolumn{3}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr 3\hsize+4\tabcolsep+2\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{%
    Viene visualizzato un messaggio di errore Login fallito che invita l'utente a riprovare o a registrarsi se non ha un account. } \\
 \hline Primary Actor &
  \multicolumn{3}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr 3\hsize+4\tabcolsep+2\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{%
   Utente non registrato. } \\
 \hline Trigger & \multicolumn{3}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr 3\hsize+4\tabcolsep+2\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{%
    L'utente conferma i dati del login premendo sul tasto Login.} \\

  \hline \multirow{2}{*}{Description} & Step & User Action & System \\

  \cline{2-4} & 1 & L'utente inserisce i dati nei relativi campi & \\
  \cline{2-4} & 2 & L'utente invia i dati premendo sul pulsante "Login" & \\
  \cline{2-4} & 3 & L'applicativo invia i dati al server e prova il login & \\
  \cline{2-4} & 4 & L'applicativo completa il login e visualizza la home page & \\
 \hline \multirow{2}{*}{Extensions} & Step &
  User Action & System \\
 \cline{2-4} & 1a & L'utente richiede l'accesso con Facebook\newline \hspace*{1em} 3a1. abc \newline \hspace*{1em} 3a2. xyz& \\ \hline
  \multirow{2}{*}{Subvariations} & Step & User Action & System \\

  \cline{2-4} & & & \\
 \hline Notes & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{} \\
 \hline


\end{tabularx}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!